# rotations between orthographic and perspective camera

Tags: camera, three.js, perspectivecamera, orthographic

I am having issues with my ThreeJS application. The problem is that the scene is rotated if I switch between perspective and orthographic view.

Perspective camera:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, threeD.offsetWidth / threeD.offsetHeight, 0.001, 10000000);
camera.position.x = 400;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

Orthographic camera:

```
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(threeD.offsetWidth / -2, threeD.offsetWidth / 2, threeD.offsetHeight / -2, threeD.offsetHeight / 2, 0.0001, 10000000);
camera.position.x = 400;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

And the results:

Perspective:
[image]

Orthographic:
[image]

As you can see, left/right, top/bottom, are inverted.
Does it make sense?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312740/all-is-inverted-when-i-use-orthographic-view/20313710#20313710

Comment: Unrelated tip regarding your perspective camera parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717513/stl-rendering-with-threejs/26725521#26725521

Comment: thanks sorry I didn't find this stackoverflow entry. Can you add a response so I can accept it?

Comment: I feel it is better to link, rather than duplicate the answer. Do you feel differently? You can upvote the link if you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All is inverted when i use orthographic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312740/all-is-inverted-when-i-use-orthographic-view)